# Find JSON value using variable from function

Tags: node.js, json, function

I'm working on a function where I need to be able to input a string which is a key in a JSON object then I need to be able to take the actual object and tack on the string to get the correct value from the JSON

```
function contact(contact_method) {
let method = array[place].settings.contact_method; // Example for contact_method is 'first_contact_method'
console.log(method)
}
```

The idea is I have 3 different contact methods and I'd like to be able to use the same function for all 3. I know the code above is barely a function but I think it shows what I want to be able to do.

I could not find anything on MDN or SO about this. I had tried using ES6 and string with `` but that did not work it just returned `[object Object].first_contact_method`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access keys of objects with a variable by using `[]`.
For instance:

```
const obj = { a: 4, b: 5, c: () => { /* do something*/}, d() { /* do something*/ } }
const keyA = 'a'
const keyC = 'c'
const valueA = obj[keyA] // valueA === 4
const methodC = obj[keyC]
// Call method c
methodC()
// or short
obj[keyC]()
// and even for "real" methods
obj['d']()
```

Comment: Since the OP is looking for dynamic _method_ names, the literal syntax is `{ a(){}, b(){} }`, but the lookup is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I added this in the sample

Comment: You only added an arrow function, not a [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).